# How to test all possible combinations with True/False Statement in python?

Tags: python, pandas, logic, boolean-logic

I have two DataFrames where each column contain True/False statements. I am looking for a way to test all possible combinations and find out where "True" for each row in df1 also is "True" in the corresponding row in df2.

In reference to the data below, the logic would be something like this:

For each row, starting in column "Main1", test if row is equal to True and if row in column "Sub1" also is True. Next, test if row in "Main1" is equal to true and if rows in column "Sub1" is True and column "sub2" also is True. In this case, if all values are True, the output would be True. Then repeat for all columns and all possible combinations.

df1:

```
   Main1  Main2  Main3
0   True  False   True
1  False  False  False
2  False   True   True
3  False  False   True
4  False   True   True
5   True   True   True
6   True  False  False
```

df2:

```
    Sub1   Sub2   Sub3
0  False  False   True
1  False   True  False
2   True  False   True
3  False  False  False
4   True   True  False
5  False  False  False
6   True   True   True
```

The output would be similar to something like this.

Of course, I could do this manually but it would be timely as well as there would be rooms for errors.

```
   Main1Sub1  Main1Sub1Sub2  ...  Main3Sub2Sub3  Main3Sub3
0      False          False  ...          False       True
1      False          False  ...          False      False
2      False          False  ...          False       True
3      False          False  ...          False      False
4      False          False  ...          False      False
5      False          False  ...          False      False
6       True           True  ...          False      False

[7 rows x 18 columns]
```

Any help on how to tackle this problem is appreciated!

Comment: Can you clarify which combinations you want? For example, are Main1Sub1Sub3, Main1Main2Sub1, Main1Main2, Sub1Sub2 combinations you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `combinations()` function in [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to extract all the possible combinations of the columns of the 2 data frames, and then use the `product()` function in [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.product.html) to identify the rows where all the columns in the considered combination are equal to `True`. I included an example below, which considers all combinations of either 2 or 3 columns.

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Main1": [True, False, False, False, False, True, True],
                    "Main2": [False, False, True, False, True, True, False],
                    "Main3": [True, False, True, True, True, True, False]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Sub1": [False, False, True, False, True, False, True],
                    "Sub2": [False, True, False, False, True, False, True],
                    "Sub3": [True, False, True, False, False, False, True]})

df3 = df1.join(df2)

all_combinations = list(combinations(df3.columns, 2)) + \
                   list(combinations(df3.columns, 3))

for combination in all_combinations:

   df3["".join(list(combination))] = df3[list(combination)].product(axis=1).astype(bool)

df3.drop(labels=["Main1", "Main2", "Main3", "Sub1", "Sub2", "Sub3"], axis=1, inplace=True)

df3

   Main1Main2  Main1Main3  ...  Main3Sub2Sub3  Sub1Sub2Sub3
0       False        True  ...          False         False
1       False       False  ...          False         False
2       False       False  ...          False         False
3       False       False  ...          False         False
4       False       False  ...          False         False
5        True        True  ...          False         False
6       False       False  ...          False          True
```

Comment: That's amazing! Thank you for taking your time helping me, I found that it very helpfull!