# All possible outcomes with large dataset in Pandas and sorting the results

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with 700 rows and 5100 columns. Each row contain True or False. With this df, I want to test all possible combinations of the columns, and with the results test if each row is equal to True.

I recieved excellent help from a fellow user the other day in this thread: [How to test all possible combinations with True/False Statement in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61027875/how-to-test-all-possible-combinations-with-true-false-statement-in-python), suggesting me to use "combinations" from itertools and "product".

This works fine working with a small dataset. However, when applying this method to my (much larger) dataset, I run out of memory when testing combinations of more than 2.

My desired output would be likewise to the example below, but a way where I dont run out of memory.

Thank you for any help.

Suggested method with small dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Main1": [True, False, False, False, False, True, True],
                    "Main2": [False, False, True, False, True, True, False],
                    "Main3": [True, False, True, True, True, True, False]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Sub1": [False, False, True, False, True, False, True],
                    "Sub2": [False, True, False, False, True, False, True],
                    "Sub3": [True, False, True, False, False, False, True]})

df3 = df1.join(df2)

all_combinations = list(combinations(df3.columns, 2)) + \
                   list(combinations(df3.columns, 3))

for combination in all_combinations:

   df3["".join(list(combination))] = df3[list(combination)].product(axis=1).astype(bool)

df3.drop(labels=["Main1", "Main2", "Main3", "Sub1", "Sub2", "Sub3"], axis=1, inplace=True)






df3

   Main1Main2  Main1Main3  ...  Main3Sub2Sub3  Sub1Sub2Sub3
0       False        True  ...          False         False
1       False       False  ...          False         False
2       False       False  ...          False         False
3       False       False  ...          False         False
4       False       False  ...          False         False
5        True        True  ...          False         False
6       False       False  ...          False          True
```

Comment: What is it you are trying to "test"?  What you are trying to do above will not fit in any memory....  choose(5100, 2) is 13 million combinations.  choose(5100, 3) is over 22 billion combinations.

Comment: Finding every combination from 5100 unique columns is going to require a LOT of memory. From my interpretation of your problem it might be useful reading this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination

Comment: Both of you are correct, and thank you for the link that you provided Francis. Would it be possible to loop through the DataFrame and perform the method above for each column independantly? I believe that ≈90% of the combinations would only contain "False" and therefore not be needed for my purpose. Thank you!

Comment: The core problem is you are going to have too many columns in the output to be usable.  If you pursue the above in using combinations for columns, your data frame will have in excess of 22 billion columns, which is nonsensical.  So your only hope is to use to use the itertools `combinations` as a generator and keep the results out of the data frame.  Are you only looking for combinations that are not "all false"?

Comment: I understand, and that is indeed nonsensical. To answer your question, I'm "only" looking for the combinations that are not "all false"! I think that approximately 90% or even more would result in all false.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the issue is? You cannot expect people to benchmark/profile your code and rewrite it for you, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I'm not real proud of this one, but maybe it has a chance of victory... :)

I think you need to get out of the data frame, because it cannot grow large enough to hold your results properly.  If your results are predictably sparse, you could use an alternate structure, like below.

Note this will be a long loop for what you are doing, 22B x length of data frame, so over a trillion hits, but if you only have to do it once, who cares.  The combinations function in `itertools` is a generator, so it will be memory efficient.

I think you are looking for results that are "all True" above as you are using the product operator.  I mis-stated in comments.

You could add to this below with a second loop to cover the combinations of size 2 if it ever completes!  :)

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations

df = pd.DataFrame({ "Main1": [True, False, False, False, False, True, True],
                    "Main2": [False, False, True, False, True, True, False],
                    "Main3": [True, False, True, True, True, True, False],
                    "Sub1": [False, False, True, False, True, False, True],
                    "Sub2": [False, True, False, False, True, False, True],
                    "Sub3": [True, False, True, False, False, False, True]})

print(df)
data = df.to_dict('index')

# test to see if it looks right for row 0
print(data[0])

# now the data is in a nested dictionary, which should be more "iterable"
results = []

for combo in combinations(df.columns, 3):
    for key in data:  # iterate through the rows in the data...  index is key.
        values = set(data[key][col] for col in combo)
        if all(values):
            results.append((key, combo))

# inspect results...
for result in results:
    print(f'row: {result[0]} columns: {results[1]} product is TRUE')
```

Yields:

```
   Main1  Main2  Main3   Sub1   Sub2   Sub3
0   True  False   True  False  False   True
1  False  False  False  False   True  False
2  False   True   True   True  False   True
3  False  False   True  False  False  False
4  False   True   True   True   True  False
5   True   True   True  False  False  False
6   True  False  False   True   True   True
{'Main1': True, 'Main2': False, 'Main3': True, 'Sub1': False, 'Sub2': False, 'Sub3': True}
row: 5 columns: (0, ('Main1', 'Main3', 'Sub3')) product is TRUE
row: 0 columns: (0, ('Main1', 'Main3', 'Sub3')) product is TRUE
row: 6 columns: (0, ('Main1', 'Main3', 'Sub3')) product is TRUE
row: 6 columns: (0, ('Main1', 'Main3', 'Sub3')) product is TRUE
row: 6 columns: (0, ('Main1', 'Main3', 'Sub3')) product is TRUE
row: 2 columns: (0, ('Main1', 'Main3', 'Sub3')) product is TRUE
row: 4 columns: (0, ('Main1', 'Main3', 'Sub3')) product is TRUE
row: 4 columns: (0, ('Main1', 'Main3', 'Sub3')) product is TRUE
row: 2 columns: (0, ('Main1', 'Main3', 'Sub3')) product is TRUE
row: 4 columns: (0, ('Main1', 'Main3', 'Sub3')) product is TRUE
row: 2 columns: (0, ('Main1', 'Main3', 'Sub3')) product is TRUE
row: 4 columns: (0, ('Main1', 'Main3', 'Sub3')) product is TRUE
row: 2 columns: (0, ('Main1', 'Main3', 'Sub3')) product is TRUE
row: 6 columns: (0, ('Main1', 'Main3', 'Sub3')) product is TRUE
[Finished in 0.6s]
```

Comment: Wow, just wow!! I've tested it out and while its too soon to say anything yet, it seems like it defiently does the trick!  I have no idea how to thank you but I'm extremley greatful for your help with this. I will defiently come back with the results. And once again, thank you very much!

Comment: super.  just be hopeful that your result set is much smaller than 10%, because even 10% positive rate probably won't fit in memory in dictionary.  Might be able to compress the result somehow or not store it at all, depending on what you need to do.